# add field to association table

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

Hello I have a relation beetwen two tables (Message, Person) many to many (m:n)

Now in this table (mm table) I have two fields. Message_id and person_id. I want to add there field with date so I have

message_id,person_id,mydate

I can`t add it in any of those two models cause the date is important for the association. How can I add it and how can I get it in code ? The only idea that I've got is to create a class that is called Message_person (like my table) and add there 3 fields, message_id, person_id, mydate but I'm not sure I can do something like this

Answer (score 0):

You are right. You have to create a third model holding your information : `date`.

Comment: only date ? or all 3 fields ? when I'll create new class how the many to many relation should be mapped ?

Answer (score 0):

Your new table should look like this:

```
public class MessageByPerson {

   @ManyToOne
   private Message message;

   @ManyToOne
   private Person person;

   @Column
   private Date date;

}
```

Comment: and I do same `@OneToOne` in Message and Person ?

Comment: I updated my answer with `@ManyToOne`, and you'll have to use `@ OneToMany` in the other classes.